# soapui + groovy + mongo db assert issue

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy, soapui, ready-api

With given code I try to connect to mongo db than, select event by Event type, than assert for what I just selected

```
@Grab('org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.4.1')

import com.mongodb.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI
import com.mongodb.DBCollection
import com.mongodb.DB
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

class MongoService {
    private MongoClient mongoClient

    def login = "user"
    def password = "pass"
    def host = "host"
    def port = port
    def databaseName = 'mongodb'

    public MongoClient client() {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(
               new StringBuilder("mongodb://").
               append(login).append(":").
               append(password).append("@").
               append(host).append(":").
               append(port).append("/").
               append(databaseName).toString()))
                              ;

        return mongoClient
    }

    public DBCollection collection(collectionName) {
        DB db = client().getDB(databaseName)

        return db.getCollection(collectionName)
    }
}

def service = new MongoService(databaseName: 'mongodb') 
def foo = service.collection('events')

BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    whereQuery.put("EventType", "test");

    DBCursor cursor = foo.find(whereQuery);
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        log.info(cursor.next())

    }
    def json = cursor.next()

    def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
     def result = slurper.parseText(json)
      assert result.EventType == "test"
```

I return soapui returns java.util.NoSuchElementException error at line:52
Manual chceck in mongodb with same query `db.getCollection('events').find({"EventType": "test"})`
returns 1 object. I have no idea how to make it work... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you're accessing the cursor.

You have already exhausted the cursor when you call `log.info(cursor.next())` and when you do `cursor.next()` there is no element to access and is the reason for that exception.

```
DBCursor cursor = foo.find(whereQuery);
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    log.info(cursor.next())
}
def json = cursor.next()
```

So the fix will be to change your code to call `cursor.next()` one each iteration in the while loop.

Comment: Thanks, I missed it :)